# Not able to cover inner wrapper class in salesforce

Tags: apex, unit-test

**Controller**

```
public class MultiplePOCShippingAddressCaptureCon {
    public class OrderAddressWrapper
        {
            public MS_Address_Junction__c add{get; set;}
            public Address__c addressSelect{get; set;}
            public Boolean selected {get; set;}
            public Boolean isOrderAdr{get;set;} 
            public Boolean disableInstallAdd{get;set;}
            public string comAdr{get;set;}      
           // public Boolean isShippingAndInstallAdrSame{get;set;}
            public OrderAddressWrapper(MS_Address_Junction__c a)
            {

                if( a.Address__r.Country__c == 'USA' ||  a.Address__r.Country__c =='United States' ||  a.Address__r.Country__c =='US' ||  a.Address__r.Country__c =='America' ||  a.Address__r.Country__c == 'United States America') 

                    disableInstallAdd=true;
                else
                    disableInstallAdd=false;   
                add= a;
                selected = false;
                isOrderAdr = true;
                comAdr = createAddress(a);

            }
    }
```

Unable to cover in below Test class

```
 private class MultiplePOCShippingAddressCaptureConTest{private static testMethod void orderAddressWrapperTest(){
            Account acct = TestDataUtility.createAccount(false);
            acct.Billing_Street__c = 'mg road';
            acct.Billing_City__c = 'pune';
            acct.Billing_State_Province__c = 'maharashtra';
            acct.Billing_Zip_Postal_Code__c = '411057';
            acct.Billing_Country__c = 'India';
            acct.BillingStreet= 'mg road';
            acct.BillingCity= 'pune';
            acct.BillingState= 'maharashtra';
            acct.BillingCountry = 'India';
            acct.BillingPostalCode = '411057';
            insert acct;
            system.assertEquals(1, [SELECT count() from Account where Id =: acct.Id]); 

            Opportunity opty = TestDataUtility.createOpportunity(false);
            opty.AccountId=acct.id;
            insert opty;
            system.assertEquals(1, [SELECT count() from Opportunity where Id =: Opty.Id]);

            List<Address__c> lstAddrs = TestDataUtility.createAddresses(false, 3, opty);
            lstAddrs[0].Type__c='Shipping';
            lstAddrs[1].Type__c='Shipping';
            lstAddrs[2].Type__c='Shipping';
            lstAddrs[0].Country__c ='USA';
            lstAddrs[1].Country__c='United States';
            lstAddrs[2].Country__c='America';

            insert lstAddrs;
            system.assertEquals(3, [SELECT count() from Address__c where Id =: lstAddrs]);

            List<MS_Address_Junction__c> lstMsAddr=TestDataUtility.createOpportunityAddresses(lstAddrs,false,opty);
            system.debug('Ms Junticon obj:::::'+ lstMsAddr);
            lstMsAddr[0].Whom_To_Ship__c ='End User';
            lstMsAddr[0].Type__c='POC ShipTo';
            insert lstMsAddr[0]; 
            system.assertEquals(1, [SELECT count() from MS_Address_Junction__c where Id =: lstMsAddr]);

            PageReference pageRef = Page.MultipleOrderShippingAddressCapturePage2;
            pageRef.getParameters().put('id', lstMsAddr[0].id);
            Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

            MS_Address_Junction__c msJuntion = new MS_Address_Junction__c();
            Address__c addr = new Address__c();
            Boolean selected;
            Boolean isOrderAdr;
            string comAdr;

            ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(opty);
            MultiplePOCShippingAddressCaptureCon controller = new MultiplePOCShippingAddressCaptureCon(sc);
            controller.OrderAddressWrapper oAddWrap = new controller.OrderAddressWrapper(msJuntion,addr,selected,isOrderAdr,comAdr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is curious that you have asserts to make sure your mock data is successfully mocked but no asserts to verify your actual code does what it is supposed to do

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line (if in this line you are trying to cover your inner class else add the line.)

```
controller.OrderAddressWrapper oAddWrap = new controller.OrderAddressWrapper(msJuntion,addr,selected,isOrderAdr,comAdr);
```

to

```
MultiplePOCShippingAddressCaptureCon.OrderAddressWrapper oAddWrap = new MultiplePOCShippingAddressCaptureCon.OrderAddressWrapper(comAdr);
```

You need to initialise the instance of inner class using outer class.